# Should I merge gh-pages with the master branch?

Tags: git, github-pages

I got two branches now that I can't merge because they have nothing in common.

1. master
2. gh-pages

Will there be trouble if I keep it this way or should I try and keep one branch for both gh-pages and master? (It's github enterprise and not on github.com.)

I can view the pages that are created and edit the pages. I just wonder if I should keep two branches with nothing in common or merge gh-pages with the master branch.

Comment: Nope, you don't need that. The *gh-pages* branch is just a suitable way to have one repository for both: project itself and project web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days you do not have to use a `gh-pages` branch.

1. Settings
2. GitHub Pages
3. Source
4. master branch /docs folder

This way you can keep everything on one branch, and still keep code separate
from documentation.

> [image: source]